# setup a mysql database through c++

Tags: c++, mysql

I would like to ask if I can setup a mysql database in c++ (using vs2005)? Like the connection that is done in mysql workbench (hostname, port, username, password) and the tables needed. Also if a .sql script can be ran in c++ so that the database can be transferred in another computer? If this is possible, can anyone please tell me? Or can this only be done manually in mysql workbench? I'm a little new to coding in c++ and with mysql. If this is possible then I can create a mysql database when installing the program I'm creating. Thank you.

----------------edit----------------------

here is the code I am using for opening the connection of the database:

```
#define SERVER "localhost" 
#define USER "root"
#define PASS "smile"
#define DATABASE "proxycardsim"

//Opens the text file that holds the list of registered IDs.
bool regID::openFile() {
bool recon = 1;

theInstance.connects = mysql_init(NULL);    // If instance didn't initialize say so   and exit with fault.

mysql_options(theInstance.connects, MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT, &recon);

//Check whether the connection to the database will go through.
if(mysql_real_connect(theInstance.connects,SERVER,USER,PASS,DATABASE,0,NULL,0))
{
   return true;
}
else{
   return false;
}

}
```

as you can see the server, user, pass and database name is defined on the program. What I would like is to create the connection to mysql during program initialization. And do the database creation too.

Comment: What kind of application do you want to build with C++ ? C++ is a programming language only.

Comment: The system is actually a tailgater logger system, my part is a login simulator. An installer is needed. I was hoping I can just create a mysql database on installation. If the database exists then it needs not create but if not, I have to create one.  It will serve as a database to hold employee information.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor The login simulator is created in C++ and is connected to a mysql workbench connection.

Comment: You can use a library to connect to an existing mysql server and do whatever you want.

Comment: I've edited my post. Actually it is about what if i have no existing mysql server connection, only the mysql server installed in the computer so the user does not have to do anything but install it.